# Combination of functions

Tags: function, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is create a string object with asterisks which can be scaled by user input. Example, User input 4:

```
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

So I had 2 seperate functions, one which creates the top and bottom part "****"
and one which creates the middle. It worked when I had them seperate, I would just print topbottom, print middle, print tobbottom. But I want to use print only once so I combined the 3 functions into the code below.

```
user = input("How many times?")
def hollow(user):
    # top
    var = ""
    for s in range(user):
        var += "*"

    # middle
    output = ""
    middle = "*"
    for x in range(1, user - 1):
        middle += " "
    middle += "*"
    amount = user - 2
    for i in range(0, amount):
        if i == (amount - 1):
            output += middle
        else:
            output += middle
            output += "\n"

    # bottom
    var2 = ""
    for z in range(user):
        var2 += "*"

    final = var + output + var2
    print(final)

hollow(user)
```

This is the output i get with this code:

```
How many times?4
*****  *
*  *****
```

So the question here is: how do I get this code to run the shape I showed in the start of this post?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: If you want to use ```print``` only *once*, did you consider *returning strings*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the line breaks to your final variable:

```
final = var + '\n' + output + '\n' + var2
```

Note that your code can be reduced to this:

```
def hollow(user):
    print ('*' * user + '\n' + ('*' + ' ' * (user-2) + '*\n') * (user-2) + '*' * user)

hollow(4)
```

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the linebreaks for top and bottom because I thought I already implemented them.